# an open interval $I$ is the union of open sets $G_n$, $m(I)=\Sigma m(G_n)$, can "=" hold non_trivially?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

First we define the measure of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in the way Павел Николаевич Натансон does in his textbook on real analysis: for an open set $G$, it is the union of denumerable open intervals $(a_n, b_n)$ such that  $(a_n, b_n)\subset G$ but the boundary point $a_n$, $b_n$ are not in $G$, then the measure of $G$ is $m(G)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(b_n-a_n)$.
***Now here goes my question:*** As is stated in Павел’s book, if the open interval $(a, b)$ is the union of denumerable open sets $G_1, G_2,…, G_n,…$, then $b-a\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}m(G_n)$. The case that simply $G_1=(a, b)$, $G_n$ empty for $n\geq 2$ is a trivial condition where “=” holds. Is there any “non-trivial” example in which the “=” holds? Or is the above example the only case that “=” holds?
***I guess that only the above case can hold the “=”, but failed to prove it.*** It suffices to consider the case that all $G_i$ are open intervals. I have proved that given at most denumerable open sets, if any two of the open intervals has empty intersection, then the union of these open intervals can not be an open interval,  but does this help the proof?

Comment: Well, $(0,4) \cup (1,5) = (0,5)$ is an open interval.  In the interesting cases with $(a,b) \subseteq \bigcup G_n$, the sets $G_n$ are not disjoint, and then you get strict inequality $b-a< \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} m(G_n)$

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, the open intervals should satisfy the condition that any two of them has empty intersection, and then their union can not be an open interval. I have edited this. And the reason why the inequality strictly holds for non-disjoint intervals is exactly where I got stuck. Could you please show how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly observed, the open sets $G_n$ cannot be pairwise disjoint (except in the trivial case) since $I$ is connected.

On the other hand, if $G_k \cap G_m \neq \emptyset$ for some $k \neq m$ then $G_k \cap G_m$ has positive measure (it is still open, so it contains an interval).
Therefore the inclusion-exclusion principle tells us that
$$\sum_{n} m(G_n) \geq m(\bigcup_{n \neq m} G_n)+m(G_m)= m(\bigcup_{n} G_n)+m(\bigcup_{n \neq m} G_n \cap G_m)\geq m(\bigcup_{n} G_n) + m(G_k \cap G_m) > m(\bigcup_{n} G_n)=b-a$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why $\sum_{n} m(G_n)> m(\bigcup_{n} G_n)$ holds? Though it is obvious intuitively, I am not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: As I said it follows from the inclusion-exclusion principle: $$m(A \cup B)=m(A)+m(B)-m(A \cap B)$$ I edited the answer, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Well, I now understand it. Thanks for your answering!